# How to avoid call onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirestoreException error) for message deleted using the snapshotListener with firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in Java with the method:

```
 firestore.collection("myCollection").addSnapshotListener(listener);
```

My listener is:

```
 EventListener<QuerySnapshot> listener = new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        WriteBatch wb = firestore.batch();
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirestoreException error) {
           snapshots.forEach(doc -> {
                // do something with the doc and then delete it
                ...
                wb.delete(doc.getReference()
        }
        wb.commit(); 
}
```

The problem is that when I delete the documents I call again the `onEvent` method. There is a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way to avoid it?

Sure there is. What you are doing is adding a real-time listener which is triggered every time you make a change at your `myCollection` location. Doesn't matter if it's a delete, write or even an update operation, the `onEvent()` method fires. To avoid this, you should get the data only once by using Query's [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get()) method. This is the correspondent `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method from Firebase Realtime Database.

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> There is a way to use the listener and having the onEvent fired only with create (or create and update) operations?

Yes, it is, you can view the changes between snapshots using a switch statement, as explained the official documentation regarding [changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

> It is often useful to see the actual changes to query results between query snapshots, instead of simply using the entire query snapshot. For example, you may want to maintain a cache as individual documents are added, removed, and modified.

Comment: But in this way, with get() method, I have to schedule my call each 2 minutes (for example) instead with the listener I have the new data immediately. The only problem is that once I read the new data I want to delete it but this operation fire the onEvent() again. There is a way to use the listener and having the onEvent fired only with create (or create and update) operations?